# Surjectivity of the mod function

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

When is the mod n function surjective on the domain of the prime numbers?

Obviously when n is an even number bigger then 2 it can not me surjective, but is something broader known?

Comment: See [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Comment: @Math_Buddy what did you consider unclear to the question? While mod n is indeed used as an equivalence relationship, it is also used to denote the remainder when dividing by n. (the quotient image of the equivalence relationship)

Comment: Yeah, yeah it's correct ,I think on it and it's indeed possible to define a function such way!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $n$ is given, and we want to know whether for every $d\in\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ there is some prime $p$ such that $p\equiv d \bmod n$.

Note that $p\equiv 0 \bmod n$ needs to have a solution too, and this means that there needs to be a prime divisible by $n$. It follows immediately that $n$ must itself be a prime.

If $n$ is prime, then every $d$ in the range $1\le d<n$ is coprime to $n$, and [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) proves that there are infinitely many primes that work for each $d$.

So the mod-$n$ function is surjective over the primes if and only if $n$ is itself prime.

**Edit:**
In the above I am assuming $n>1$. The $n=1$ case trivially works too.